# The RESET button is refreshing the filter bar as well in Jqgrid.?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jqgrid

I Have a problem in the reset, as you see i have set the status default as ACTIVE, and only one record can be selected, after selecting the record user can click ADD WO

http://i48.tinypic.com/11udoo6.jpg

But when click on the Reset button the whole status bar changes

http://i45.tinypic.com/25a6vcp.jpg

I also set the dafaultvalue to ACTIVE also..!! 
I Have to keep the status active, when it resets..!!Plz help me

```
function initJqGridSearchSubProject(table,pager,msg,loadSelID,caption,chkMrk ){

 $(table).empty();
 $(table).GridUnload();
 var mygrid =jQuery(table).jqGrid({
    datatype: "local",      
    data:msg,   
    width: 1240,
    scrollOffset:0,     
    height: 250,
    colNames:['ID','PID','Project Folder Name','Sub Project Name','Responsible','Status','Last Updated On'],
    colModel:[
    {name:'id',index:'id',hidden:true, width:5, sorttype:"int", editable: false,resizable:false},
    {name:'pid',hidden:true, width:5, sorttype:"int", editable: false,resizable:false},
    {name:'projectFolderName', width:250, editable: true,formatter:'tsLinks'},
    {name:'subProjectName', width:250, editable: true,formatter:'subProjectLinks'},
    //{name:'eCNNumber', width:150, editable: true},                
    {name:'responsible', width:200, editable:false,resizable:false},
    {name:'status', width:100,editable: true,stype:'select',edittype:"select",resizable:false,searchoptions:{defaultValue:"ACTIVE"},editoptions:{value:"ACTIVE:ACTIVE;INACTIVE:INACTIVE;DELETED:DELETED",readonly:false},editrules:{edithidden:false}}, 
    {name:'lastUpdatedOn', width:200,editable: false,resizable:false,sorttype:'date',formatter:'date',formatoptions:{ srcformat: 'M d y H:i:s', newformat: 'd M y h:i A' }}

        ],
    pager: pager,
    rowNum:200,     
    rowList:[200,400,600,1000],
    //rowTotal:2000,                    
    //loadOnce:true,    
    //rownumbers:true,
    gridview : true,
    sortname: 'lastUpdatedOn',                  
    viewrecords: true,
    sortorder: "desc",                  
    toppager:true,
    multiselect:true,
    singleselect: false, 
    //multiboxonly:true,
    //toolbar: [true,'both'],                   
    caption:caption,
    hidegrid: false,
    gridComplete:function(id){
    //$(chkMrk).hide();
    //alert('grid complete');
    },
    beforeSelectRow: function(rowid, e)
    {
        // reset check box selection only when user clicks on another checkbox
        if($(e.target).is("input:checkbox"))
        {
            // reset/clear other checkboxes selection before making a latest clicked row's checkbox as selected
            jQuery(table).jqGrid('resetSelection');
        }

        // Code To Disable Check Box Selection When User Selects by Clicking on A Row
        return $(e.target).is("input:checkbox");
        //return(true);
    }

}); 
jQuery(table).jqGrid('navGrid',pager,{del:false,add:false,edit:false,search:false,refresh:true,cloneToTop:true,afterRefresh:function(){}},{},{},{},{}); 
jQuery(table).jqGrid('navButtonAdd', table+ '_toppager_left',{caption:"Add WO", buttonicon:"ui-icon ui-icon-plus",id:"SUBPROJID", onClickButton: function(){},position:"first",title:"Add WO"});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally got the result, i just added the triggerToolbar() inside the reset button function.

```
jQuery(table).jqGrid('navGrid',pager,{del:false,add:false,edit:false,search:false,refresh:true,cloneToTop:true,afterRefresh:function(){$(table)[0].triggerToolbar();}},{},{},{},{});
```

And now its working fine..!

Answer (score 0):

What you have done is that you have set the `defaultValue` option in `searchoptions` and not in `editoptions`. You just have to add the same there. Just try changing the definition of `status` column as below :

```
{name:'status', width:100,editable: true,stype:'select',edittype:"select",
resizable:false,searchoptions:{defaultValue:"ACTIVE"},
editoptions:{value:"ACTIVE:ACTIVE;INACTIVE:INACTIVE;DELETED:DELETED",
readonly:false, defaultValue:"ACTIVE"},editrules:{edithidden:false}},
```

**Update :**

To call the line inside of [beforeRefresh](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3anavigator#parameters) event handler you can do as follows :

```
jQuery(table).jqGrid('navGrid',pager,
  { edit:false,view:false,add:false,del:false,search:false,
    beforeRefresh: function(){
        alert('Here');
        jQuery(table).jqGrid('setGridParam',{datatype:'json'}).trigger('reloadGrid');
    }
  });
```

Comment: Still am getting the same issue...i think there's something to do with the reset..should we declare any function..???

Comment: Can we set the defaultValue: ACTIVE in reset button..?

Comment: I dont think so. when `refresh` is set to `true` a reset button is a result on the toolbar.When the button is clicked a `trigger(“reloadGrid”)` is executed and the search parameters are cleared

Comment: If you need to do some actions before refresh will be started you should use `beforeRefresh` callback:

`$("#grid_id").jqGrid('navGrid', '#gridpager', {`
    `beforeRefresh: function () {`
        `// some code here`
    `}`
`});`
Else you should set `refresh : false` and use your own custom button

Comment: So shall i remove the searchoptions in the status row?

Comment: That would just not set the value to 'ACTIVE' as default

Comment: 'jQuery(table).jqGrid('navGrid',pager,{del:false,add:false,edit:false,search:false,beforeRefresh: function(){
        alert('beforeRefresh');
        grid.jqGrid('setGridParam',{datatype:'local'}).trigger('reloadGrid'[{current:true}]);
    },cloneToTop:true,afterRefresh:function(){}},{},{},{},{});

'
Its not Happening..the page is not refreshing..??

Comment: Outside the line! in the sense..we should use it outside reset button..?

Comment: i was trying for beforerefresh like this
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3772334/how-to-get-jqgrid-reload-to-go-to-server

Comment: tried giving beforeRefresh as you said but still the issue persists,the checkbox is being checked.when i press the reset button.